# Determine the encoding of a text file

Tags: character-encoding

I have a txt file I am trying to determine the encoding of. I open it in Firefox and click on View-> Character encoding and it says ISO-8859-1. If I open it in Notepad or Notepad++ it says ANSI.

So I am now confused.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211683/how-to-determine-text-encoding - in short : you can only make a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSI, and ISO-8859-1 are both common mislabels for Windows-1252. If the characters look correct, then the file is encoded in Windows-1252.

Note that ISO-8859-1 is a real encoding (ANSI is not an encoding at all), it's just that Windows-1252 encodes useful characters  in the range `0x80-0x9F`, which are otherwise wasted in ISO-8859-1.