# Read/write .txt file with special characters

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file-io, character-encoding

I open **Notepad** (Windows) and write

```
Some lines with special characters
Special: Žđšćč
```

and go to **Save As...** "someFile.txt" with **Encoding** set to **UTF-8**.

In Java I have

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("someFile.txt"));
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {                         
    printLine(line);
}
in.close();
```

But I get question marks and similar "special" characters. Why?

**EDIT:** I have this input (one line in .txt file)

```
665,Žđšćč
```

and this code

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, line, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",");
    String[] article = p.split(line);

    Toast.makeText(mContext, article[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(mContext, Integer.parseInt(article[0]), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
in.close();
```

And **Toast** output (for ones who aren't familiar with Android, Toast is just a method to show a pop-up on screen with particular text in it) is fine. Console shows "weird characters" (probably because of encoding in console window). But it fails at parsing an integer because console says this (`warning: toast output is just fine`) - [Problem](http://slike.hr/slike/snag0022_f3402.jpg.html)?

It seems like the String is containing some "weird" characters which Toast can't show/render but when I try to parse it, it crashes. Suggestions?

If I put ANSI in NotePad it works (integer parsing) and there are no weird chars as in the picture above, but of course my special characters aren't working.

Comment: What's in that printLine(line) function?

Comment: `while((line = in.readLine()) != null)` - Does Java even let you do that? I thought in Java, assignments weren't considered expressions...

Comment: @Will printLine just prints it to my Debugger (Eclipse) - in this case second line becomes "01-04 20:01:23.394: VERBOSE/line(32246): Special: Å½ÄÅ¡ÄÄ"

Comment: while((line = in.readLine()) != null) - Yes you can do this Eric. The condition that the while loop is evaluating is (A != null) where A is the result of reading one line from the in stream.

Comment: actually my problem is little different actually my file name is Žđšćč and i got error FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("Žđšćč.txt")); plzz help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the output console which doesn't support those characters. Since you're using Eclipse, you need to ensure that it's configured to use UTF-8 for this. You can do this by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding > set to UTF-8*.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

**Update** as per the updated question and the comments, apparently the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is the culprit. Notepad by default adds the UTF-8 BOM on save. It look like that the JRE on your HTC doesn't swallow that. You may want to consider to use the `UnicodeReader` example as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888189/java-readers-and-encodings/1888284#1888284) instead of `InputStreamReader` in your code. It autodetects and skips the BOM.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
UnicodeReader ur = new UnicodeReader(fis, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(ur);
```

---

Unrelated to the actual problem, it's a good practice to close resources in `finally` block so that you ensure that they will be closed in case of exceptions.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new UnicodeReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF-8"));
    // ...
} finally {
    if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

Also unrelated, I'd suggest to put `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",");` outside the loop, or even make it a static constant, because it's relatively expensive to compile it and it's unnecessary to do this everytime inside a loop.

Comment: It isn't because my SQLite INSERT also doesn't work. If I manually type in (on my HTC Desire) as input "žđšćč" and forward it to INSERT statement - it works fine. If I, however, use read function to read those same characters from my .txt file - crash. So, it's not just console output. Something else?

Comment: I updated the code above...I really don't know what the heck is going on =/

Comment: Does it now look right on output console or not? Another cause can be that your SQLite JDBC driver and/or DB is not treating the characters as UTF-8.

Comment: Here is partial answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599061/unable-to-parse-as-integer. Document (.txt file) IS UTF-8, but why my reader isn't reading it as UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks right - but a very common, and easy, error is to misstake what is printed to screen to what's in the String. Check with a debugger if the string isn't already read right.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad does not save special symbols correctly. I had a similar problem and I used Notepad++ instead and selected UTf-8 encoding from there. When I did this, my program no longer crashed when applying String library methods to it unlike when I created the text file in Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad may not be able to handle non-ascii characters. Try another text editor. If you want to stick to what's available in windows install, try wordpad.

Comment: He has chosen UTF-8 in Notepad's *Save As* option.

Comment: If I use Wordpad and Save it as "text-document" it fails at the 2nd line. If I use unicode text format it crashes on the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Not all sequences of bytes are valid UTF-8."
```

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

under "Invalid byte sequences" for specific details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the character the conversion as part of servlet request/response ?
If yes, 
`request.setEncoding("UTF-8")`
 or
`response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")`

should solve your purpose.