# Read special characters in java with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read/write .txt file with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597749/read-write-txt-file-with-special-characters)

Im reading a file but I dont know how to read the accents and special caracters, here is mo code for read I read I have to add a different codification but i dont know how to doit

```
File file = new File("C://fichero.csv");

BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;

    line = bufRdr.readLine();
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this since it is marked as a duplicate of question that uses explicit charset, while accepted answer here suggests the problem was in not specifying the charset. Also, this Q was now used as a dup target.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
File file = new File("C://fichero.csv");

BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"ISO-8859-1"));
String line = null;

line = bufRdr.readLine();
```

Comment: Why not use **UTF-8**?

Comment: because UTF-8 does not include all characters. e.g German Umlauts.