# BufferedReader/Writer not working correctly with Special Chars

Tags: java, bufferedreader, encryption, bufferedwriter

I ran into a little problem with `Cipher` and `BufferedReader/Writer` in Java. Everything works fine, if anyone wants my code nethertheless I can post it if you want. The problem is if I try to convert the encrypted bytes to a String (which works fine) then write it to a file with `BufferedWriter` with the following setup:

```
    FileWriter fwrit = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter buffwrit = new BufferedWriter(fwrit); //The writer itself
String encTextString = new String(encText,"ISO-8859-1"); //The String that gets written later
```

This setup lets the Writer write special chars and I think the problem is not here (if it is please tell me). (Yes I already checked if decrypting without writing it to a file and loading again works and it does work.) The problem is I cant get the `BufferedReader` set up correctly, is there a way or a other writertype that reads the chars correctly?

Comment: could it be a possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9281629/2231632

Comment: I already tried what was suggested in that question some time ago, didnt work for me.

Comment: As Russell suggested, did you try with the OutputStreamWriter?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`FileWriter` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

"Convenience class for writing character files. The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an `OutputStreamWriter` on a `FileOutputStream`."

The default charset is probably UTF-8. So, if you want to write ISO-8859-1, you would need to do:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
```

More to the point, though, if your goal is to get the encoded bytes into the file without alteration, then...

"`FileWriter` is meant for writing streams of characters. For writing streams of raw bytes, consider using a `FileOutputStream`."

Comment: like this? BufferedWriter buffwrit = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),"ISO-8859-1"));

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better not to use FileWriter, that class is just a convenient class to wrap a FileOutputStream into a OutputStreamWriter.

OutputStreamWriter has constructors to encode your non ascii characters using a specific encoding.

FileWriter lacks those....

Comment: There is still something wrong. I used your method and the same ISO-8859-1 encoding. The results: Stuff that got written: [B@16d19d73 E�z�9�� Stuff that got read: E?z?9?? [B@5ccc078