# Using BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am doing a method involving BufferedReader and I to have use it as an input argument, can someone tell me how to use it as an input argument but initialize it outside the method?

Other thing is, how do I get the buffer to read special characterS? (eg:   ´, ~)

```
public static List<Pacote<Pair<String, Double>>> create(
BufferedReader fileReader, int capacidadePacotes)
throws IOException {
        List retorno = new ArrayList <> (6);
        String s;
        while ((s=fileReader.readLine())!=null){
            retorno.add(parseItem(s));
        }
        return retorno;

    }
```

It basically reads a file and sends it to another function that treats the text and creates objects based on that, I'm just not clear on the whole using BufferedReader as an input argument, have just used it inside the method before so I'm unclear on how to initialize it properly, probably a dumb question but I would like to know how to do it properly

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want to do, so do you want to read a file? do you want to pass a buffered reader object to a constructor? What have you tried (show us code).

Comment: "s=fileReader.readLine())!=null"? Have you written right code?

Comment: That's part of the question, I really dont understand the BufferedReader bit of this, I normally do a cycle like that to read the buffered file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the BufferedReader object as follows if you are trying to read a file.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
    int capacidadePacotes = 10;
    create(rdr, capacidadePacotes);
}
//urcode for create
```

The buffered reader can read line by line using the readLine() method. If you read null that means you reached the end of the file. A more readable way to use the buffered reader would be the following:

```
String s = rdr.readLine();
while(s != null) { //while u didn't reach the end of the file
    //your code
    s = rdr.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Wasnt considering the main class!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize it "outside" the method, why not hand it over like that:

```
create(new BufferedReader(reader, 3));
```

Or how exactly do you want it to have instantiated? For the instantiation, you need a Reader, which can be handed over. If you want to create a Reader from a file, the answer is also in the following link.

How to read special characters with a BufferedReader:

[Read special characters in java with BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281629/read-special-characters-in-java-with-bufferedreader)