# JAVA - Reading InputStream stops when finds ampersand

Tags: java, android, byte, inputstream

I'm reading a HTML source from URL using simple Input/Output Stream

```
URL website = new URL(url);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("pagina.html", 0);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 2000000);
fos.close();
```

When trying to read what i've downloaded

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.openFileInput("pagina.html")));
String line;
String content="";
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
   content += linea;
```

It stops when a "&&" is found.
Original content (using Chrome's code viewer) is:

```
function addFav() {if (navigator.platform.substring(0,3) == 'Win' && navigator.appName.substring(0,3)=='Mic') {
    document.write('<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Añadir esta página a Favoritos" onClick="window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title);" class="aTxtPortail">Añadir a Favoritos<\/a>');
} else if (window.sidebar&&window.sidebar.addPanel){
    document.write('<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Añadir esta página a Favoritos" onClick="window.sidebar.addPanel(document.title,location.href,\'\');" class="aTxtPortail">Añadir a Favoritos<\/a>')
}
}
```

But readed code ends on:

```
function addFav(){if (navigator.platform.substring(0,3) == 'Win' ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Is there any consideration with the ampersand character when reading byte buffers? Thanks.

Comment: What is the class of context?

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281629/read-special-characters-in-java-with-bufferedreader

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but it seems to be a different problem, since Charset specification on reader does not change much the output. InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"ISO-8859-1");InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is,"ISO-8859-1"); By the the way, the conflicting source is http://es.kingofsat.net/pos-19.2E.php

Comment: Thanks, solved using Jsoup.connect() method of Jsoup library.