# What's going on with Java Buffered Reader's readline () read result as null?

Tags: java, io

This is my code.
What's going on with Java `BufferedReader`'s `readline()` read result as `null`?

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\db.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String str =br.readLine();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read special characters in java with BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281629/read-special-characters-in-java-with-bufferedreader)

Comment: @smoggers Where did you get the part about special characters from?

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: @Thilo originally the question featured several unknown chars like you would see with encoding scheme issues

Comment: Before asking here on StackOverflow you should take a look at the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend you to get the actual file location and copy that path, then replace all the \ with /. then paste it to your code.

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader.readLine() returns null if the end of the stream has been reached. In your case the file is empty. If the path to the file would be wrong the constructor of FileReader would throw a FileNotFoundException .