# How can I get scanned string to contain special characters?

Tags: java

Sorry if this is painfully obvious, but I am new to Java. I was unable to find anything answering this (at least not that I could understand). What I want to accomplish is for, when the user enters the square root symbol `(√)`, the string to contain said symbol. However, when I print it, it is simply a question mark. Here is my code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.next();
System.out.println(s.substring(0,1));
```

I am guessing that it has something to do with the scanner as when I set it up like this, it works properly.

```
String s = "√";
System.out.println(s.substring(0,1));
```

Is there some (preferably simple) way to accomplish this? My goal is not to print the character that they enter, but rather for it to be read in as `√`. In case anyone is curious. I am currently working on a simple calculator with a couple functions (including the square root). Obviously, I could have the user type something like "sqrt" instead, but I would prefer to do it this way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/write .txt file with special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597749/read-write-txt-file-with-special-characters)

Comment: The problem probably is not your code;  it’s that your output is being printed in a console that cannot display that character.

Comment: @VGR My console displays that character in my second example.

Comment: Oops, I misread.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Scanner class reads UTF-8 encoded text by default, so replace your scanner instantiation with:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8");
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly does the "utf-8" do? Also, it still prints a question mark.

Comment: @JavaNewbie UTF-8 is a character encoding. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your input charset is not UTF-8. Try this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in,Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

Comment: Are there any imports I need? Both InputStreamReader and Charset say "cannot find symbol."

Comment: @JavaNewbie What version of java are you using ? Charset class was added in Java 7: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: I believe NetBeans is using Java 7. Under IDE Log, Java, it says 1.7.0.

Comment: @JavaNewbie ok, maybe IDE issue. try to use fully qualified class name e.g. java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()

Comment: That took care of "cannot find symbol" error, but the result is the same as before: a question mark.

Comment: @JavaNewbie well, I ran your sample and it worked for me, so it's about the encoding. Maybe your IDE uses different encoding. Which one do you use ?

Comment: Also as I'm not an expert in NetBeans, but you may try following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219249/netbeans-console-does-not-display-bangla-unicode-characters